# Chef ruby_block execution leads to error

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra, devops

I have a problem with some `chef` code I wrote. The shell command in the ruby block is always executed before everything else. As long as the package is not installed, the bin is not available. Every try to chain this somehow failed.

ERROR:

```
Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - icinga2

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/tmp/cookbooks/hit_icinga2/recipes/icinga2_client.rb:25:in ``'
  /var/tmp/cookbooks/hit_icinga2/recipes/icinga2_client.rb:25:in `block in from_file'
  /var/tmp/cookbooks/hit_icinga2/recipes/icinga2_client.rb:23:in `from_file'
  /var/tmp/cookbooks/hit_icinga2/recipes/default.rb:8:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/tmp/cookbooks/hit_icinga2/recipes/icinga2_client.rb:

 18:    package 'icinga2' do
 19:      action :install
 20:    end
 21:  end
 22:
 23:  ruby_block 'name' do
 24:    # get Icinga version output
 25>>   get_icinga_version_information = %x[icinga2 -V]
 26:    #we clean up
 27:    #lines.first - just return first line of output
 28:    ##chomp - remove line break
 29:    #scan- match regex
 30:    #flatten - flatten array
 31:    #[n] - use array element number n
 32:    #to_s - convert to string
 33:    #split - split string at caracter
 34:    #gsub - search and replace

System Info:
------------
chef_version=13.6.4
platform=centos
platform_version=7.3.1611
ruby=ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=chef-solo worker: ppid=7301;start=16:37:42;
executable=/opt/chefdk/bin/chef-solo
```

CODE:

```
package 'icinga2' do
  action :install
end

ruby_block 'detect_icinga_version' do
  # get Icinga version output
  get_icinga_version_information = %x[icinga2 -V]
  #we clean up
  #lines.first - just return first line of output
  ##chomp - remove line break
  #scan- match regex
  #flatten - flatten array
  #[n] - use array element number n
  #to_s - convert to string
  #split - split string at caracter
  #gsub - search and replace
  #to_i - convert to integer
  clean_icinga_version =         get_icinga_version_information.lines.first.chomp.scan(/version: [^)]*/).flatten.to_s.scan(/[0-9\.-]+/)[0].to_s.split('-')[0].gsub('.', '').to_i
  if clean_icinga_version < 280
          icinga_pki_path = '/etc/icinga2/pki'
  else
          icinga_pki_path = '/var/lib/icinga2/certs'
  end
end
```

Any idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was interesting. Chef declined the proper chaining and set conditions. Its now an Ohai Plugin that gets a reload after the package installation happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code in a block with `block do ... end` as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to either give entire path of icinga2 in the below line

get_icinga_version_information = %x[icinga2 -V]

or add the parent directory of this icinga2 to environment variables